Stop OneDrive in Scheduled Task
I need to stop and resume OneDrive inside a PowerShell Script that runs at Scheduled Task.
The stop/resume works fine unless I check 'run whether user is logged on or not'. In that case the OneDrive didn't stop even if the user configured in task is the same that runs the OneDrive (the only user in that computer).
The problem is that I need the option to run wether user is logged on or not.
Start-Process "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe" /shutdown


Is the goal to ensure One Drive is completely disabled on the machine and it will not start no matter what regardless of the user that logs in? If so, I have a brute force way I can write up for you when I get time that does just that. It is a combination of scripts, and group policies. It should work for Office 365 or Office 2021 LTSC as I have confirmed. It does not require giving non-admin users elevated permissions as the other answer suggests.

Standard Windows users cannot schedule profiles to run when they are
not logged in, unless they are given the "Log on as batch job" access right.
To give a user this permission :

Run secpol.msc
Position to
Security Settings / Local Policies / User Rights Administration
Double-click "Log on as a batch job"
Use "Add User or Group..." to add the user.

For more information see the article
Log On as Batch Job Rights: How to Grant Access.
